# Estimate the condition number in the second norm of the matrix An

Tags: numerical-methods, condition-number

Let $A_{n}$ be a matrix of size $n$ for $n \geq 1$, and a structure:

$$
A_{n}=\left[\begin{array}{cccccccc}
\sqrt{21} & 1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \sqrt{21} & 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{21} & 1 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{21} & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & \sqrt{21} & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & \sqrt{21} & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{21}
\end{array}\right]
$$

Estimate the condition number in the second norm of the matrix $A_{n}$.

My solutions is as follows

$$
\|A\|_{2}=\sqrt{\lambda_{\max }\left(A^{*} A\right)}=\sigma_{\max }(A) .
$$

where $\sigma_{\max }(A)$ represents the largest singular value of matrix $A$. So

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\left\|A_{n}\right\|_{2}=\sqrt{21} \\
&\left\|A_{n}^{-1}\right\|_{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{21}}
\end{aligned}
$$

Condition number

$$
\mu=|| A_{n} \| \cdot|| A_{n}^{-1}||=1
$$

I want to check if this is correct and I'm used to only solving this for symmetric matrices

Comment: No, it is not correct. You stated correctly what the singular values are, but then used the eigenvalues.

Comment: Oh okay, so I should use the square root of the biggest eigen value not the square root of the biggest number

Answer (score 1):

As you indicated, you essentially need to estimate the eigenvalues of $A^*A$.

Fortunately, in this case it is easy to compute $A^*A$ explicitly.
$$
A^*A=\left[\begin{array}{cccccccc}
22 & \sqrt{21} & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\sqrt{21} &22 & \sqrt{21} & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \sqrt{21} &22 & \sqrt{21} & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{21} &22 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots &22 & \sqrt{21} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & \sqrt{21} &22 & \sqrt{21} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & \sqrt{21} &22
\end{array}\right]
$$

You can now bound the eigenvalues of this matrix using the [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem), which tells you that they must be in $[22-2\sqrt{21},22+2\sqrt{21}]$.

Now,
$$
22-2\sqrt{21} = (\sqrt{21} - 1)^2, \text{ and}\\
22+2\sqrt{21} = (\sqrt{21} + 1)^2.
$$
Therefore, an estimate for the condition number of $A$ is
$$
\frac{\sqrt{21} + 1}{\sqrt{21} - 1}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Estimate the condition number in the second nom of matrix $A_{n}$

You can now bound the eigenvalues of this matrix using the Gershgorin circle theorem, which tells you that they must be in

$|\lambda-\sqrt{21}| \leqslant 1 \Rightarrow \lambda \in\langle\sqrt{21}-1, \sqrt{21}+1\rangle$

$\operatorname{cond}_{2}(A)=\sqrt{\frac{\lambda_{\max }\left(A^{\top} A\right)}{\lambda_{\min }\left(A^{\top} A\right)}}$

note:

$\sqrt{\lambda_{\max }\left(A^{T} A\right)}=\sigma_{\max }(A)$

$\sqrt{\lambda_{\min }\left(A^{T} A\right)}=\sigma_{\min }(A)$

$=\frac{\sigma_{\max }(A)}{\sigma \min (A)} \mid \begin{gathered}\sigma_{\operatorname{max}}(A) \text { represents the } \\ \text { largest singular value } \\ \text { of matirx } A \text {. }\end{gathered}$

$=\frac{\sqrt{21}+1}{\sqrt{21}-1}$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You are applying Gershgorin's circle theorem to the matrix $A$ rather than $A^TA$ which is what you should do.

Comment: Yeah but applying it to A still produces the exact same solution, I've tested it with multiple matrices.